# What is causing ubuntu 20.04.5 to become inaccessible via SSH?

Tags: shutdown, sshd, logs

For a long time I ran Ubuntu 16LTS as my home server. After setting up a new server with Ubuntu 20 there are times where I simply cannot access the server via SSH. As far as I can tell, the system has powered off as there is no fan activity to indicate it is on. The system is connected to the same UPS as the old server and is well within the capacity of the UPS. The UPS status usb is not connected.

When I check all logs there is no evidence that anything turned the machine off or put it into sleep. The syslog simply stops recording messages on some date. After starting the machine I must always force shut down and restart. I assume it is stuck at the grub menu but cannot confirm since I cannot connect a monitor to the machine. The syslog then starts again when the os loads after I successfully unlock it via initfs. last-x shows only the second time I boot the machine (ie, after the force reboot).

To make things clearer: The last message in syslog is october 9th until I unlocked the system october 16th at 16:02.

Things I tried to find more info:
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/auth.log
last -x
last reboot

In the ssh logs I see no attempts to connect while the system is unresponsive and no logs of any kind of failure with sshd.

When I try this:
grep -E -i -r ’error|warning|panic’ /var/log/

I get no error messages from October 9th until october 16th at 16:04 with the possible exceptions of the journal files which I am not familiar with. To be clear, the journal files have no dates listed in the output likely because of their binary format.

Is there some other logging I am missing? What could possibly be causing this? I never had this problem on the previous machine and am at a loss on where to look next to make progress on the issue.

Comment: There are a few things that could be causing this issue. One possibility is that the server is not properly configured to go into sleep mode or hibernate mode. Another possibility is that there is a problem with the server's power supply. If the server is not properly configured to go into sleep mode or hibernate mode, it is possible that the server is shutting down due to a power outage or because the server is not receiving enough power. If the server is not receiving enough power, it is possible that the UPS is not providing enough power to the server or that the server is not plugged into

Comment: To ensure the UPS may not be causing issues I ran a test by unplugging the UPS. Since the server is physically connected directly to the UPS it can't be a misconfiguration in that sense. Furthermore, no power events have been logged by the UPS in the last week.

Comment: I updated the version info. I included it in the title but abbreviated it for simplicity in the post. I don't remember what version of Ubuntu 16 I ran. I just wanted to make it clear that I was able to run another ubuntu server in the same environment without issue.